# With vs without egg fresh pasta cooking time

Tags: pasta

If you have identically sized/shaped/thickness of fresh pasta noodles, with egg and without, is there any difference in cooking time?

My son and his girlfriend are vegetarian and vegan, so I'm looking to make an Italian pasta dish next time we get together for a meal. Most of the recipes I see for fresh pasta are for recipes with eggs.

Any difference in cooking time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Egg v. no egg does not influence cooking time for fresh pasta. There are plenty of egg free versions.  [This is a go-to for me](https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/handmade-capunti-with-jason-stoneburner), and produces a great pasta.

Thickness...whether or not it is filled...cooking from frozen all influence cooking time a bit.  In an interview with a well-known pasta chef, I heard him state that most people (in US) over cook dried pasta and under cook fresh pasta.

Comment: Cool. The main reason is because there's tons of specifics out there for every shape and thickness of fresh pasta, so I'm not worried about those details, just if I need to adjust.  +1.  FYI - I usually wait a few days before choosing a best answer, even if I get my question answered right away.